# I am not able to connect to my SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql, database-connection, sqlconnection

```
public partial class Variables_input : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string conStr = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;

    protected void Buttonsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr))
       {
           try
           {
               con.Open();
               Response.Write("<script language ='javascript'>alert('Connection is open');</script>");
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Response.Write("<script language ='javascript'>alert('Connection Problem');</script>");
           }
           finally
           { 
                con.Close();
                Response.Write("<script language ='javascript'>alert('Connection is close');</script>");
           }
     }
}
```

I am not able to connect to connect my SQL Server database. After running this code I receive "Connection Problem". Please help.

Comment: What is the error message shown in the console?

Comment: An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: Write out the the stacktrace of the exception to the console, it will give you more information.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where to begin to start.

1. You are using SQL server not mySQL right, you have funny wording. Just want to make sure.
2. You might want to try looking at the exception data, usually it gives you an error message. You caught the error now read it.
3. If the error message is not helpful you could put a breakpoint at `con.Open()` and step into an make sure all the parameters are correct or see where the problem is if the exception error doesn't help.

Might also want to look at this:

[dot net pearl for sqlconnection](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlconnection)